# Can't connect to MongoDB from shared hosting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shared-hosting

I have created a node.js MongoDB webapp. It works fully fine in my local machine. So I hosted it with godaddy.
**Steps to host (correct me if i did something wrong)**

- Install nodejs to server
- Extracted all files in a new directory `myapp` and installed all dependencies
- Installed `pm2` globally to keep server running using `pm2 start app.js --watch` command

But when I tried to run it using `node app.js` app starts at port 3000, but shows DB connection error

My code for db is -

```
mongoose
  .connect(DB_URL, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`DB Connection Error: ${err.message}`);
  });
```

I have allowed access from all IPs in atlas already.
I get this error message -
[image: error message]

Can someone tell me how can i fix it.
**The web app run fine on local machine and on heroku**
It is my first time working on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Atlas.  Atlas requires you to whitelist any IP addresses that will be accessing the database.  My first guess is that you whitelisted your local IP address when setting up Atlas but haven't yet whitelisted the IP address for GoDaddy.

I don't use GoDaddy, but I found instructions for getting your server IP address here: [https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-ip-address-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16112#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20GoDaddy%20product,in%20the%20list%20of%20settings](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-ip-address-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16112#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20your%20GoDaddy%20product,in%20the%20list%20of%20settings).

Then go into Atlas and add that IP address to your whitelist.  Instructions for doing so are available here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: actually i allowed access from all IPs
And I also tried adding the server's IP also

Comment: Hmm... it's a bit of a guessing game at this point.  How are you setting your username and password?  Have you set them as environment variables locally and on Heroku but not in GoDaddy?

You could also try to connect to the database directly outside of Mongoose to try to narrow down the error.  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database has steps on how to do so.